# Raspberry Win 10 IoT Python PDB files not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I've some troubles while I'm trying to deploy using VS2015 in debug mode a simple python app to my Raspberry PI3.
I get these following warning errors and don't know how to resolve them.

```
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\Test7VS.Debug_ARM.stan\pythonhome\dlls\_ptvsdhelper.pyd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[916] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You background task has an exit code "0x0" indicating that it runs just fine.

The warning errors are not an issue because when you launch your app in debug mode, the debugger is trying to find the debug symbol files(pdb file), which are not found in your debug symbol path.

Don't get bothered by such warnings. However, If you really want to get rid of them, googling how to connect windows kernel debug symbols server, and hook it up in VS or windbg.

Try set a breakpoint in your StartupTask.py file to see if it can actually hit.